# Ninject Registration with Silverlight and Prism

Tags: silverlight, unity-container, prism, ninject

I am using Ninject as my bootstrapper (mainly because of convention based registration and its fluent API). 
We are using Prism 4 Navigation Framework RequestNavigateAsync call to navigate from one page to the other. The API looks into the container for named instance of the object and resolve the view / viewmodel that it needs to navigate to. Here's Unity syntax for this.

Its recommened to use 
container.RegisterType("InboxView"
instead of container.RegisterType("InboxView")

In Ninject, how can I get similar effect so that it gels with Navigation framework easily?
Can you help provide some code / documentation which shows how to register named instances in Ninject (that might help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is your syntax in Unity

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<object, InboxView>("InboxView");
```

The equivalent syntax in Ninject is

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<object>().To<InboxView>().Named("InboxView");
```

Comment: That looks like a right syntax. I can see the instance of the object when I use servicelocator to get the instance of 
this.serviceLocator.GetInstance<object>(candidateTargetContract). That's how Prism is creating instance inside its codebase. However, somehow, this still doesn't complete the navigation Process. Any ideas? Has anyone used Prism Navigation Framework with Ninject.?

Comment: Finally got it working. Looks like servicelocator was not being setup properly in the bootstrapper and after going through Prism code - I fixed that part. Thanks for the syntax.

Comment: @bkhanal I'm doing `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(Injecter.Get<IServiceLocator>);` in my bootstrapper (gets a singleton instance of my NinjectServiceLocator). The NinjectServiceLocator returns the view, but the contentcontrol with the view stays empty. How did you solve it?